# Stack Array int char C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

Good Day, 
Could someone help me,this is a kinda frustrating, how do I keep both int and char in Stack array. here's code for stack array for int only, dunno how to push with kind of (like) "Enter name" "Enter number", what code should I put and where part that I'm going to add it?
sorry for my english ..........

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int size;
int top;
int * stack_values;

void createStack(int s) {
    size = s;
    stack_values = new int[s];
    top = -1;
}
bool isFull() {
    if(top == size-1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
bool isEmpty() {
    if(top == -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void pop() {
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        top--;
    } else {
        cout << "The stack is Empty!" << endl;
    }
}

void push(int num) {
    if(!isFull()) {
        top += 1; //top++;
        stack_values[top] = num;
    }
}
void display() {
    for(int i = top; i>=0; i--) {
        cout << stack_values[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    createStack(5);

    bool loop = true;
    while(loop) {
        cout << "Choices:\n1.Push\n2.Pop \n3.Display \n";
        int choice;
        cout << "Enter Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: {
                    int number;
                    cout << "Enter number: ";
                    cin >> number;
                    push(number);
                }
                break;
            case 2: {
                    pop();
                }
                break;
            case 3: {
                    display();
                }
                break;
            case 0:
                loop = false;
                break;
            default: {
                    cout << "Invalid input";    
                    loop = false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a stack that can contain both strings and numbers, or separate stacks for each type? Use `std::variant` for the first, use a template for the second.

Comment: You probably want to store a `struct` instead of an `int`. For example: `struct Item {int number; std::string name;};`.

Comment: @Barmar wanted to separate stacks for each type but display both, is that possible?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp my prof haven't teach it yet to me/us, i don't know yet how to use struct

Comment: Yes, you can do that with templates. It would be easier if you put all the code into a class, rather than separate variables and functions.

Comment: @Barmar how? can't find any tutorial on ytube or any other references :/

Comment: Google "c++ template tutorial",  it finds several.

Comment: @Barmar ok will take a look right now, and will post after the result, and Thank you :)